# Movie where a man was put into a computer before death, wife doesn't trust him anymore

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie a few years back, I don't remember what it was called, about a man who was put into a computer (I think because of some disease or something) before he died. He was the first person ever to have this happen.

After becoming a computer he became super smart (or maybe he already was?) and invented a bunch of awesome stuff (I remember an old guy getting a needle stuck into his eye to cure his blindness, the computer-man invented it). However, when he reveals to his (still fully human) wife that he had been using his systems to monitor her hormones so he can tell what mood she's in she finds it rather upsetting and begins to feel that this isn't actually her husband, just a computer that talks like him.

At one point in the film, someone asks him how they can be sure he is truly conscious, and his answer is the same question right back at him, "How can I be sure you're truly conscious?"  (I think someone else in the movie said the same thing earlier.)

I think a major theme of the film was that no one knew whether or not he was truly conscious. I'm guessing it was made no sooner than 2000 and no later than 2014.

Comment: Transcendence with Jonny Depp? https://youtu.be/VCTen3-B8GU

Comment: https://youtu.be/0ANXgrd3f28 - Can you prove you're human?

Comment: @Valorum That's it! Turns out I was right about it not being later than 2014, although I guess it was not as old as I thought. If you post it as the answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like the movie [Transcendence](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2209764/) (2014) starring Johnny Depp and Rebecca Hall.

Depp's character is working to create an artificial intelligence, but after he is poisoned by terrorists, Hall's character (his wife) uploads his consciousness into the computer he was developing.

> Joseph Tagger: Can you prove you're self-aware?
>
> Will Caster: That's a difficult question, Dr. Tagger. Can you prove that you are?

I can't find an image of the blind guy having nanomachines injected in his eye, but that's definitely in the movie.  At the end, when the nanomachines are wiped out, he goes blind again.

Comment: Posting an answer since it seems no one else has time...  Still haven't found a screencap of healing the guy's eye.

Comment: @DavidW I'm not sure I want to see that part again, I remember distinctly because I looked away! But this is definitely it.